# What does it indicate if /proc/PID/maps shows zero for all addresses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm debugging a problem with a Linux DNS server. Curiously, when I look at `/proc/PID/maps` for the DNS server process, this is what I get:

```
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2344                  /usr/sbin/unbound
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2344                  /usr/sbin/unbound
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                     [heap]
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                     [heap]
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2009                  /usr/lib/engines/libgost.so (deleted)
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2009                  /usr/lib/engines/libgost.so (deleted)
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2016                  /usr/lib/engines/libpadlock.so (deleted)
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2016                  /usr/lib/engines/libpadlock.so (deleted)
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2333                  /lib/libz.so.1.2.8
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2333                  /lib/libz.so.1.2.8
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 1760                  /lib/libdl-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r--p 00000000 00:0e 1760                  /lib/libdl-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 1760                  /lib/libdl-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 3083                  /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 3083                  /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 1761                  /lib/libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r--p 00000000 00:0e 1761                  /lib/libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 1761                  /lib/libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 3085                  /lib/libpthread-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r--p 00000000 00:0e 3085                  /lib/libpthread-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 3085                  /lib/libpthread-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2002                  /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (deleted)
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2002                  /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (deleted)
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 3181                  /usr/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 3181                  /usr/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 3189                  /usr/lib/libldns.so.1.6.17
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 3189                  /usr/lib/libldns.so.1.6.17
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 2335                  /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (deleted)
00000000-00000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 2335                  /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (deleted)
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 1755                  /lib/ld64-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00000000-00000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                     [vdso]
00000000-00000000 r--p 00000000 00:0e 1755                  /lib/ld64-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 1755                  /lib/ld64-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so
00000000-00000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                     [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0     [vsyscall]
```

I've never seen anything like this before. All the addresses, except for the vsyscall page, are zero! Do you know what that means?

Comment: Are you sure that the app still running? I.e. it could become a zombie, so it still would be in process list.

Comment: It's definitely running, and handling DNS requests. I'm not at work right now, but will post the output of `uname` tomorrow.

Comment: Can you tell, do you see alike output full of zeroes when you do `cat /proc/self/maps`?

Comment: @Hi-Angel, I will check when at work tomorrow.

Comment: can you run it as sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [discussion in Valgrind mail list](http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/9262126/) when someone had the same problem. The issue was that the kernel have been patched with PaX patches, one of which doesn't allow to look at the `/proc/pid/maps`.

The quote about the patch [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX#Limitations)

> The second and third classes of attacks are also possible with 100% reliability, if the attacker needs advance knowledge of address space layout and can derive this knowledge by reading the attacked task's address space. This is possible if the target has a bug which leaks information, e.g., if the attacker has access to /proc/(pid)/maps. There is an obscurity patch which NULLs out the values for the address ranges and inodes in every information source accessible from userland to close most of these holes; however, it is not currently included in PaX.

Despite the phrase that the patch is not currently included, the problem at the mailing list was solved with PaX utility. I.e. it could be changed with [`chpax` utility](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/chpax/) that does permission modification on a per-binary basis, thus allowing to disable restrictions for a particular binary.

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, it turns out that this host is running a grsec kernel. I will see if I can use `paxctl` to turn off those protections.